# Навигация доступна поисковому роботу

Tags: html

Как понять, что навигация сайта доступна поисковому роботу?

Answer (score 6):

С помощью инструментов для вебмастеров, которые предоставляют все крупные поисковые системы, можно посмотреть какие страницы попали в индекс, если страницы в индексе, значит бот до них добрался.

Без доступа к аккаунту вебмастера, посмотреть какие страницы в индексе можно с помощью поисковых операторов (example.com надо заменить на свой домен):

Для Google:

```
https://www.google.ru/search?q=site:example.com
```

Для Яндекс:

```
https://yandex.ru/search/?text=site:example.com
```

Для Bing:

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=site:example.com
```

Если определенная страница в индексе, это значит что навигация до этой страницы точно доступна боту. Исключением может быть случай, когда на сайте есть XML карта сайта, в таком случае бот найдет страницы и без навигации на сайте. Проверить есть ли XML карта у сайта можно с помощью запроса к robots.txt:

```
http://example.com/robots.txt
```

Затем надо найти строку, начинающуюся с "Sitemap":

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Это будет ссылка на файл (или несколько) карты сайта.

Тут же в robots.txt проверьте какие страницы вашего сайта запрещены к индексированию с помощью директивы Disallow.

Если есть доступ к серверу, можно проверить конфиг сервера — не блокирует ли он ботов. В логах сервера можно посмотреть по каким страницам ходили боты.

Так же, можно посмотреть с помощью инструментов Google как поисковый бот видит определенную страницу https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch.
Указываете страницу, Googlebot показывает как он ее видит (ее html код). В этом html коде ищете теги , это будут те ссылки, которые бот точно видит.

Надо понимать, что Googlebot вероятно самый продвинутый и он видит сайты как минимум как браузер (или даже лучше), т.е. он выполняет JS, iframe, анализирует расположение блоков на странице, размеры шрифтов и т.д.. Например, 
Яндекс буквально недавно объявил, что их бот научился выполнять JS для некоторых популярных сайтов, а следовательно "обычные" сайты такой чести пока не удостоились.

Comment: 1) С помощью инструментов для вебмастеров - что если у меня нет доступа к панели веб мастера
2) проверить конфиг сервера - что именно там смотреть? 

Спасибо конечно, но у меня ситуация когда у меня нет доступа к сайту, но аудит нужно как то сделать!

Comment: @maard я расширил свой ответ, если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте.